# CBPeripheralManager: Does add(_ service: CBMutableService) advertise peripheral?

Tags: ios, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth, cbperipheral

**SCENARIO**

I am working on a framework that must leverage the `CoreBluetooth` framework in order to send data over BLE. I have already finished my requirement to communicate environmental data using iBeacons, but I need to send data now from one device to another.  I will be using the `CBCentralManager` from one application to `scanForPeripherals` and another application that will be broadcasting a peripheral with a `CBUUID` and then the central application will request data from the service's characteristics.

I have all of this working properly from what I can tell: **a.** I can scan for peripherals in my area and get a lot of results around the building, but not the peripheral that I broadcast from my device. **b.** I can add the service that contains my `CBUUID` from the `CBPeripheralManager` and get a success in the `didAddService` delegate method.

But my `CBPeripheralManager` still can not discover my peripheral.

**CODE**

```
// To scan...
centralManager?.scanForPeripherals(withServices: nil, options: nil)

// To broadcast...
let dataString = "SomeValueFromData"
let data = dataString.data(using: .utf8)
let base64 = data?.base64EncodedData()

let uuid = CBUUID(nsuuid: Constants.Scan.uuid)
let service = CBMutableService(type: uuid, primary: true)
let properties = CBCharacteristicProperties.read
let characteristic = CBMutableCharacteristic(type: uuid, properties: properties, value: base64, permissions: .readable)
service.characteristics = [characteristic]
peripheralManager.add(service)
```

> Note: For both `CBCentralManager` and `CBPeripheralManager` I am instantiating my managers and then waiting for the `didUpdateState` delegate methods to get called and only begin scanning or broadcasting if the state is `poweredOn`.

**HYPOTHESIS**

I think that I have my `CBCentralManager` set up correctly to scan for all peripherals (not specifying any service UUIDs), and I still can not discover my peripheral. I think there is a flaw in the 'broadcast' code. I have done some research on the `add(_ service: CBMutableService)` function on `CBPeripheralManager` and I am not sure if I am understanding this correctly.

**QUESTION**

**a.** Does the `add(_ service: CBMutableService)` begin the 'broadcast' of a `CBPeripheral`? I am under the impression that this is the only method I have to call and this will 'add' the service to some sort of queue that will be sent out on BLE to be discovered.

> From the [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corebluetooth/cbperipheralmanager/1393255-add) on the `add(_:)` method, "Publishes a service and any of its associated characteristics and characteristic descriptors to the local GATT database."

I have done a good amount of research about the local GATT database and Apple does not provide much information.

**b.** Does the local GATT database operate in the manner as the queue like I described above and will begin the 'broadcast' of my peripheral automatically? Or is there more I have to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No,  `add(_ service:)` only adds the service to the `CBPeripheralManager`. To actually advertise services you need to call [`startAdvertising(_ advertisementData:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corebluetooth/cbperipheralmanager/1393252-startadvertising).

`advertisementData` is a dictionary. You specify an array of UUIDs that you want to advertise for the key [`CBAdvertisementDataServiceUUIDsKey`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corebluetooth/cbadvertisementdataserviceuuidskey).

The reason you must do this is that a peripheral may offer more services than it advertises. Since there is limited space in the advertisement packet you generally only advertise your "primary" service; the service that is used to discover your peripheraL.  Once it is connected the central can discover the other services provided by your peripheral.